# how to not persist an entity jpa?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two mysql databases, the first one is a big one, with many tables, and currently I'm writing a java code to retrieve some simple data from this big database and put it in my second database designed on my own like this (3 tables : person , teacher and student):

```
|personID|firstname|lastname| 
|    -   |    -    |    -   |
|    -   |    -    |    -   |

|personID|Subject|Salary|   
|    -   |    -  |   -  |
|    -   |    -  |   -  |

|personID|Score|
|   -    |   - |
```

so I have 3 entities (one for each table)

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    private Long  personID;
    
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
        
}
```

- 

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(referencedColumnName="personID")
public class Teacher extends Person{
    
    private String subject;
    private String salary;
        
}
```

- 

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(referencedColumnName="personID")
public class Student extends Person{
    
    private int score;
        
}
```

so basically I have a method loadTeacher(long fk) that takes a foreignkey as a parameter, will fetch the first database and will persist the teacher corresponding to that fk.
it forks as follow :

```
laodTeacher(long fk) {
  -with this fk retrieve the firstname and lastname ,and create a Person Object (called person)
  -with this fk retrieve the subject and Salary
  -create teacher object : new Teacher(person.getFirstname,person.getLastname,subject,salary)
}
```

the problem is that I want to obtain a database designed like as mentionned earlier, so there are two solutions:

1. do not persist the person object in my method loadTeacher, beacause the person table will be automatically filled, when I will create the Teacher object
2. persist the person Object, but manage to have the same personID in both the person object created and the resulting teacher object

I don't know how to do both :/
thanks for your help, and hope I was clear in my explanation of the problem

Comment: I read your question twice and didn't understand what is the problem, and what are you trying to achieve. Can you explain it a bit more clearly?

Comment: i can be divided in two question : - how to not persist an entity (for example , i dont want to persist the person Object)           -how can the teacher object has the same personID as the person object in the table knowing that teacher object was created from the person object

Comment: you just need to set the id of the persisting object and in general in order to define custome logic and have complete control over what goes in which table, use Spring JDBC instead of JPA.

Comment: but he id is autogenerated , isn' t it ?

Comment: it is only autogenerated if you don't have it set.

Comment: but how can i set personID of Teacher object , beacause it is not an attribute

Comment: yes it is, that is how class inheritance works

Comment: ah ok i see ! so if i choose the second solution (in the question) , i will create the teacher object like this : teacher = new Teacher(person.getfirstname , person.getlastname , subject , salary )  and then teacher.setpersonID(person.getID()) , am i right ?

Comment: that would be an example yes, you could also pass it right away in the constructor and have constructor do `super(personId, firstName, lastName)`